# Concatenating variables and strings Google Colab and Bash

Tags: bash, concatenation, google-colaboratory

Let's take this command as an example:

```
!curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'nlpService': 'projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/nlp',
    'documentContent': 'Insulin regimen human 5 units IV administered.'
}" "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/nlp:analyzeEntities"
```

If I put the string `'Insulin regimen human 5 units IV administered.'` into a .txt file and assign a variable to it, how do I replace it in the original code?

This is my code, which turned out to be empty and have a different result to the first command:

```
!text1=$(cat textfile.txt)
!curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'nlpService': 'projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/nlp',
    'documentContent': '"'$text1'"'
}" "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/nlp:analyzeEntities"
```

Comment: What is `!`? Is that your shell prompt?

Comment: @Barmar, it's an escape hatch in Collaboratory (also available in IPython, IPython Notebook, Jupyter, &c) to invoke a shell for a single command in what would otherwise be a Python environment.

Comment: @SunnyLeague, note that while you tagged this question bash, `!` **does not start bash**; instead, it uses `/bin/sh`.

Comment: That said, two separate shells, whether sh or bash, can't see each others' variables, which is the immediate problem here. If you had _just one_ `!` command that both created the variable and used it, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Does the first `--data` really work? JSON uses double quotes around strings, not single quotes.

Comment: Heh, good point. Unless the server is trying to eval the input as a Python literal, it probably _doesn't_ work; moot for the purposes of the immediate question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine these into a single command so they're run by the same shell. Each use of `!` creates a new and different shell; they can't see each others' variables.

```
!text1=$(cat textfile.txt) && curl -X POST ..."$text1"...
```

By the way, I strongly recommend against doing this. Python has excellent HTTP client libraries available; it's more appropriate to use them to perform the request in-process.

Comment: I was going to import ```requests``` to run the command in Colab and get the data stored in a Python variable, but wasn't able to get past the authentication portion to run the request, especially with ```$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"```

Comment: You can invoke that and get its output with `subprocess.run`.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles commented, the problem is that you're starting separate shells to set the variable and execute `curl`, so the variable is lost.

Instead of using a variable you can put `$(cat textfile.txt)` directly into the command.

```
!curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'nlpService': 'projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/nlp',
    'documentContent': '$(cat textfile.txt)'
}" "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/services/nlp:analyzeEntities"
```